# type object 'Usuario' has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django, csv

im uploading a .csv file in django, and im taking groups of 500 lines of the csv and upload them with bulk_create, but im getting this error...

here's what im doing:

```
personas = []
Aux_USER = []
reader = csv.reader(path)
reader.next()
row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)
reader = csv.reader(path)
reader.next()
for row in reader:
    if not Usuario.objects.filter(casillero=if_empty(row[0])).exists():
        clave = "%32x" % random.getrandbits(128)
        hash = clave[0: 6]
        if len(row[4])>30 or len(row[3]) > 30:
            ErrorLog.objects.create(casillero=row[4])
        else:
            usr = User.objects.create(
                username=row[1],
                first_name=row[3],
                last_name=row[4],
                password=hash,
                email=row[5],
            )
            if not (row[5] == ""):
               # usuario_aux(
                usuario_aux.user=usr.id
                usuario_aux.clave=hash
                usuario_aux.correo=False
               # )

              #  usuario_aux.objects.create(
              #      user=usr.id,
              #      clave=hash,
              #      correo=True
              #  )
                #person_user_email(
                Usuario.user=usr.id
                Usuario.casillero=if_empty(row[0])
                Usuario.cuenta_individual=row[1]
                Usuario.integrante=row[2]
                Usuario.telefono=row[6]
                Usuario.plan_inscripcion=row[9]
                Usuario.estado=row[10]
                Usuario.municipio=row[11]
                Usuario.parroquia=row[12]
                Usuario.ciudad=row[13]
                Usuario.urbanizacion=row[14]
                Usuario.avenida=row[15]
                Usuario.tipo_inmueble=row[16]
                Usuario.codigo_postal=if_empty(row[17])
                Usuario.status=row[29]
                usr = None

                #    )
            else:
               # usuario_aux(
                usuario_aux.user=usr.id
                usuario_aux.clave=hash
                usuario_aux.correo=False
               # )
                #usuario_aux.objects.create(user=usr.id, clave=hash)
                #person_user_email(
                Usuario.user=usr.id
                Usuario.casillero=if_empty(row[0])
                Usuario.cuenta_individual=row[1]
                Usuario.integrante=row[2]
                Usuario.telefono=row[6]
                Usuario.plan_inscripcion=row[9]
                Usuario.estado=row[10]
                Usuario.municipio=row[11]
                Usuario.parroquia=row[12]
                Usuario.ciudad=row[13]
                Usuario.urbanizacion=row[14]
                Usuario.avenida=row[15]
                Usuario.tipo_inmueble=row[16]
                Usuario.codigo_postal=if_empty(row[17])
                Usuario.status=row[29]
                usr = None
                #)
        personas.append(Usuario)
        Aux_USER.append(usuario_aux)
        n_objects = len(personas)
        if row_count < 500:
            Usuario.objects.bulk_create(personas)
            usuario_aux.bulk_create(Aux_USER)
            print "listo"
            personas = []

        if n_objects == 500:
            Usuario.objects.bulk_create(personas)
            usuario_aux.bulk_create(Aux_USER)
            print "500 creados"
            row_count -= 500
            personas = []
```

when i see the admin, it only create "488" users, and never shows the print "listo" why is this happening?

Comment: It's not clear where or how row_count or personas are initialized. Since both those variables will affect how this runs, I'd focus on making sure those have the initial values you expect them to have. Or post the code that shows where they come from.

Comment: There you go @dylrei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The create() method saves the record as you create it. That's a nice convenience in many cases, but it completely defeats the purpose of using bulk_create().

I don't think that's the only problem with this code, but it explains how you're saving 488 records without printing "listo". As you refactor this, I'd recommend focusing on processing the first 10 records in your CSV correctly and *then* worry about optimizing for performance for the whole set.